# How to manipulate large images in Firemonkey?

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey

Does Firemonkey have an image manipulation library?  Right now I'm doing everything with Canvases and it sucks.

I have a program which currently loads the image into a `TBitmap`, performs its operations, and then saves the `TBitmap` object out to a file.

The `TBitmap` interface however is not ideal.  Among the problems...

- It silently scales down images which are larger than 8k pixels in any dimension, losing resolution on large .png files
- It scales the image whenever there are clipping issues with `DrawBitmap` which is undesirable (I'd much rather it clip the output or just crash)
- Rotating bitmaps is very hard to predict the output of and may scale the image.

I want a better option than canvas methods for image manipulation.  I see there are units under Vcl.Imaging, but I can't find anything similar under the FMX units.

The operations I'm really looking for are just drawing lines, text, zooming, rotating, blitting to the display, saving, and loading.